# Getting 'undefined' when accessing existing field in django admin change_form.html from custom js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to learn how to work with custom js in django admin pages.

**admin.py:**

```
class TestAdmin(nested_admin.nested.NestedModelAdmin, tabbed_admin.TabbedModelAdmin):
    
    class Media:
        js = ("admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js", "admin/js/jquery.init.js", "js/testChangeForm.js")
   
    tab_overview = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'domain', 'visible')
        }),
        QuestionAdminInline
    )
    
    tabs = [
        ('Test content', tab_overview),
    ]
```

**testChangeForm.js:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (!$) {
            $ = django.jQuery;
        }
        console.log($("#domain").val())
});
```

change_form.html from django admin contains select/option element with name="domain", but when I try to access it, it gives me undifined. I tried various suggested things, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: `name` or `id` ?

Comment: I can't believe I made this stupid mistake. I wanted id, but used string for name. Thanks, I would have probably lost more time on this.